# App crashing during NSUserDefault data removal

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults, iphone-sdk-4.1

When I call this function my app gets crash.
I got this error : `[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1].`
How i can resolve it please help if you know.

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSDictionary *dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
      for (id key in dict)
      {
          NSObject * object = [dict objectForKey:key];
          if(object != nil)
          {
              [defs removeObjectForKey:key];
              [defs synchronize];
          }
      }
```

Comment: what you trying to do clear all user default ? then   NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

Comment: sorry mike 
i try your suggestion but its not working, app getting creash

Comment: [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Comment: can you please add exception break point and check the line where app crash

Comment: ya i added it and set zombi enable and check it

Comment: but it can't found

Comment: There is nsstring ,bool and nsdata store in nsuserdefault

Comment: Can you add some other code?

Comment: Show your full coding

Comment: yes i found it ,
now i resolve it and its working fine Thanx...

Comment: Better to post your solvable answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121339/discussion-between-user3182143-and-kaushik-movaliya).

Comment: i set break point as you say and found that this method is working perfectly but problem is set on root view controller

Comment: because of this problem viewwillappiar method call, and i get data from NsuserDefault in viewwillappiar method so it's can't provide data because of we already remove nsuserdefault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use following code. It should help you

```
NSString *applicationDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:applicationDomain];
```

You can also use

```
    NSDictionary *defaultsDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
    for (NSString *key in [defaultsDictionary allKeys]) {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //outside loop.
```

**NOTE: The crash which you are mentioning is regarding setValue ForKey in a Dictionary. Kindly user breakpoint and see where you are inserting nil value in Dictionary.**

Comment: I try this code its not working for me my app getting crash

Comment: [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Comment: there is nsstring ,bool,nsdata store in nsuserdefault

Comment: It seems that insertion code is somewhere else, not here, I can't find any insertion in any dictionary. kindly review your code, or try to comment our setValue in dictionary below or after the above code @KaushikMovaliya

Comment: i set break point as you say and found that this method is working perfectly but problem is set on root view controller.

Comment: because of this problem viewwillappiar method call, and i get data from NsuserDefault in viewwillappiar method so it's can't provide data because of we already remove nsuserdefault.

Comment: Accept answer if my answer or comments helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121408/discussion-between-kaushik-movaliya-and-veer-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

try adding the keys of the desired entries into NSArray inside the loop
then do removeObjectsForKeys:array outside the loop

It's preferable to not remove entries while enumerating inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

My solution for your question is

```
NSUserDefaults *defs  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dict = [userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {
    [dict removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[defs synchronize];
```

Comment: Thank you for remaining that brother.I removed that line.See my answer.